# Writing user data to QTcpSocket

Tags: qt

How can I write user data to QTcpSocket and read it in

```
QTcpSocket * sock = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your socket, you can just hook it up via signals/slots to get the data. You will need to save the socket via an instance variable.

Header:

```
QTcpSocket* sock;
```

Implementation File:

```
YourClass::someMethod {    
    this->sock = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(this->sock, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(startRead()));
}

void YourClass::startRead {
      char buffer[1024] = {0};
      this->sock->read(buffer, client->bytesAvailable());
      cout >> buffer >> endl;
      this->sock->close();
}
```